# Simple arithmatic error javascript

Tags: javascript, math, jsfiddle

When I do the following operation :

```
    var score = (0.229*5) /
            + (0.237*5) /
            + (0.265*5) /
            + (0.214*5) /
            + (0.055*5);
```

Score evaluates to `2.478305190973909`. However, if the same operation is performed on a single line.

```
var score = (0.229*5) + (0.237*5)+ (0.265*5)  + (0.214*5)  + (0.055*5);
```

Score evaluates to `5.000000000000001` as I intend.

What gives? Why can't I split the operation onto multiple lines?

EDIT:

JSFiddle is giving me an error when doing:

```
var score = (0.229*5) 
            + (0.237*5) 
            + (0.265*5) 
            + (0.214*5) 
            + (0.055*5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MSamman/Jdrbq/

However, this is fixed by doing

```
var score = (0.229*5) +
            (0.237*5) +
            (0.265*5) +
            (0.214*5) + 
            (0.055*5);
```

Apparently it didn't like starting a line with `+`.

Comment: Why the `/`s? Are you trying to divide?

Comment: im trying to carry over to the next line.

Comment: I'm not surprised they are different, one does division the other does not!

Comment: You do not need a `/` to carry over to the next line

Comment: and if you did need to carry over to the next line (cause you were dealing with strings), it would be `\` instead

Comment: Without that I get a "Bad break before +" using JSFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate the `/` operator (it's doing division)

```
var score = (0.229*5)
            + (0.237*5)
            + (0.265*5)
            + (0.214*5)
            + (0.055*5);
```

Use `//` to start a single line comment.

The `;` terminates a statement, although JavaScript interpreters will imply semi-colons at certain times. See http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons for more info regarding statement termination.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it as

```
var score = (0.229*5) 
            + (0.237*5) 
            + (0.265*5) 
            + (0.214*5) 
            + (0.055*5);
```

Which seems to work for me

Comment: it's better to put the "+" at the end of the line than at the beginning, especially if you are opening the next line with a paren...

Comment: I see. I guess my issue was that I was using JSFiddle as a quick syntax checker and it doesn't like this. However, if I put the + at the end of the line instead of the begging, JSFiddle doesn't produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can split, just do not use the / at the end of the lines.
Javascript evaluates one statement being between ; characters, regardless white space characters.